# What is とう in 行きとうない

Tags: meaning, dialects

I tried researching it myself and came away with the possible meaning of ている in dialect. Is that right? If it helps, this is the line I happened upon the とう in question:

> 私はもう行きとうない

Comment: You have actually been using this 「とう」 in saying 「ありがとう」 ever since you started learning the language.

Comment: 文法的なことではなく、単にウ音便についての言及でした。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“行きとうない” is the same as “行きたくない” in the standard Japanese.
“私はもう行きとうない” means that *I don’t want to go anymore*.

Comment: @Tsukasa: I think people would say “我はもう行きとうない” rather than “私はもう行きとうない.” “行きとうない” sounds a bit archaic.

Comment: @eltonjohn: "行きとうない" is still around in some areas, not always western Japan. I think that using "我は" as the subject-case of the first person is out-of-date. Sorry, I wish I were a Japanese linguist.