# What does "gataku" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 守ってもらいたいわけでもないのに、なぜこんなにもこの場所を離れがたく思うのだろう.

What does "gataku" mean in this sentence? I don't know if this is some kind of suffix or grammar point I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[がたい](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/06/27/jlptn2-grammar-gatai/) is close to にくい and comes after the masu-stem of a verb, meaning "difficult to do something"

From [デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%84_%28%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%29/)

> 難い（がたい）
> ［接尾］《形容詞型活用［文］がた・し（ク活）。形容詞「かた（難）い」の濁音化》動詞の連用形に付いて、その動作の実現が困難であることを表す。…しにくい。…するのがむずかしい。「得―・い」「信じ―・い」「いわく言い―・い」

I believe it's in [JLPT grammar](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2018/06/27/jlptn2-grammar-gatai/):

> [意味]
> 〜するのが難しい。
> 「能力的にできない」ということには使わない。
>
> [英訳]
> "difficult to do"
> ＊Not used to mean something can't be done because of lack of ability.

- 離れる　→　離れ　ます　→　離れがたい　→　離れがたく(連用形)　→　離れがたく思う

離れがたい: difficult to leave

離れがたく思う: reluctant to part/leave

Comment: @Lokitan - You have been using this がたい without knowing it. ありがとう is derived from 有りがたく.

Comment: What exactly are the derivation steps there?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Could you be a bit more specific? Which steps would you like me to expand on? I thought the arrow-linked line was clear. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I mean between 有りがたく and ありがとう.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's an ウ音便. See this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91525/30454

Comment: Oh, so it's a euphonic shift and not an actual grammatical derivation? I had assumed that the おう vowel combination indicated a volitional, as it typically would. But of course, that wouldn't allow it to appear before ござる. Right.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - See also: [Historical prospective of ウ音便 transformation (e.g. 有難く => 有難う)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42890/43676)